# What is the difference between the days and "d" property in DateInterval

Tags: php, datetime

When I use the DateInterval class it returns a property names "d" and then another property names "Days" I am really confused on what is the difference between the two. Can someone please explain.

Below is an example of the object that was returned in my code.

```
DateInterval(
y =
0
m =
1
d =
1
h =
3
i =
16
s =
6
weekday =
0
weekday_behavior =
0
first_last_day_of =
0
invert =
1
days =
31
special_type =
0
special_amount =
0
have_weekday_relative =
0
have_special_relative =
0
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a DateTime class and not a DateInterval class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- `d` - the days <s>from the start of the month</s> that need to be added after the months are added - `(Feb 23 - Jan 1).d == 22`)
- `days` - the total number of days - `(Feb 23 - Jan 1).days == 31 + 22`)

From [the documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

> #### d
>
> Number of days.
>
> #### days
>
> If the DateInterval object was created by DateTime::diff(), then this is the total number of days between the start and end dates.
> Otherwise, days will be FALSE.
>
> Before PHP 5.4.20/5.5.4 instead of FALSE you will receive -99999 upon
> accessing the property.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did read the documentation, but I didn't know that d would be the number of days from the start of the month which is what got me confused. Thanks

Comment: @json2022: Actually, that's not quite the right meaning, but it's never greater than 31